# html dropdown menu that interacts with mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I've recently changed my code in the index.php of my website and now the mysql dropdown menu isn't working. It's taking me back to the home page and not other pages of the table in mysql. I've most likely deleted something but I'm unsure of what. Here is my index.php html code:

```html
<form method="post" action="http://www.450s.co/index.php">
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p style="font-family: 'Arial'; color: black;">Select your town/city:</p>
                    <select id="change_city" name="city" class="dropdown-style center">
                        <option value="24">Bedfordshire</option>
                        <option value="46">Buckinghamshire</option>
                        <option value="5" selected="">Greater London</option>
                        <option value="39">Hertfordshire</option>
                        <option value="44">Lincolnshire</option>
                        <option value="45">Northamptonshire</option>
                        <option value="47">Nottinghamshire</option>
                        <option value="23">Oxfordshire</option>
                        <option value="42">Reigate</option>
                        <option value="41">Slough</option>
                        <option value="40">St Albans</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p style="font-family: arial; color: black;">Select your postcode:</p>
                    <select name="code" id="change_postcode" class="dropdown-style">
                        <option value="1">BR - Bromley</option>
                        <option value="2">CR - Croyden</option>
                        <option value="3">DA - Dartford</option>
                        <option value="4">E - East London</option>
                        <option value="5">EC - City of London</option>
                        <option value="6">EN - Enfield</option>
                        <option value="7">HA - Harrow</option>
                        <option value="8">IG - Ilford</option>
                        <option value="9">KT - Kingston upon Thames</option>
                        <option value="10">N - North London</option>
                        <option value="11">NW - North West London</option>
                        <option value="12">RM - Romford</option>
                        <option value="13">SE - South East London</option>
                        <option value="14">SM - Sutton</option>
                        <option value="15">SW - South West London</option>
                        <option value="16">TW - Twickenham</option>
                        <option value="17">UB - Southall</option>
                        <option value="18">W - West End</option>
                        <option value="19">WC - West Central</option>
                        <option value="20">WD - Watford</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p style="font-family: arial; color: black;">Select your trade:</p>
                    <select name="cat" class="dropdown-style center">
                        <option value="1">Aerials</option>
                        <option value="2">Air Conditioning</option>
                        <option value="3">Airport Transfers</option>
                        <option value="58">Architectural Services</option>
                        <option value="4">Auto Electricians</option>
                        <option value="5">Bathrooms</option>
                        <option value="6">Beauty Salons</option>
                        <option value="7">Bedrooms</option>
                        <option value="8">Blinds and Curtains</option>
                        <option value="9">Boilers</option>
                        <option value="10">Brake and Clutch</option>
                        <option value="11">Builders</option>
                        <option value="12">Burglar Alarms</option>
                        <option value="13">Car Body Repairs</option>
                        <option value="14">Car Hire</option>
                        <option value="15">Carpenters</option>
                        <option value="16">Carpet Cleaning</option>
                        <option value="17">Carpet Fitting</option>
                        <option value="18">Central Heating</option>
                        <option value="20">Chiropodists</option>
                        <option value="51">Chiropractors</option>
                        <option value="22">Cleaning Services</option>
                        <option value="59">Conservatories</option>
                        <option value="61">Damp Proofing</option>
                        <option value="23">Domestic Appliance Repair</option>
                        <option value="24">Double Glazing</option>
                        <option value="25">Drains</option>
                        <option value="62">Driveways</option>
                        <option value="26">Electricians</option>
                        <option value="49">Estate Agents</option>
                        <option value="27">Exhausts</option>
                        <option value="63">Fascias, Soffits &amp; Guttering</option>
                        <option value="28">Fencing</option>
                        <option value="50">Flooring</option>
                        <option value="29">Garage Doors</option>
                        <option value="30">Garage Services</option>
                        <option value="33">Gardeners &amp; Landscapers</option>
                        <option value="31">Gas Engineers</option>
                        <option value="32">Guttering</option>
                        <option value="65">Handyman</option>
                        <option value="54">Health &amp; Beauty</option>
                        <option value="57">Hearing Aids</option>
                        <option value="34">Kitchens</option>
                        <option value="35">Locksmiths</option>
                        <option value="36">M.O.T</option>
                        <option value="56">Mobility</option>
                        <option value="55">Optitions</option>
                        <option value="37">Painters and Decorators</option>
                        <option value="38">Paving Contractors</option>
                        <option value="39">Pest Control</option>
                        <option value="40">Plasterers</option>
                        <option value="41">Plumbers</option>
                        <option value="42">Removals and Storage</option>
                        <option value="43">Roofing</option>
                        <option value="64">Sheds</option>
                        <option value="44">Skip Hire</option>
                        <option value="66">Tiling</option>
                        <option value="45">Tree Services</option>
                        <option value="46">Tyres and Exhausts</option>
                        <option value="47">Vets</option>
                        <option value="53">Website Design</option>
                        <option value="48">Wills &amp; Probate</option>
                        <option value="60">Windows</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="GET MY DISCOUNT" class="standard-button"></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

and the php code:

```
<?php

include('mysql.php');
include('template/header.php');

$city = str_replace('-', ' ', $_GET['city']);

$result = $sql->sql_query("SELECT * FROM city WHERE city LIKE '%".$city."%' LIMIT 1");
$row = $sql->sql_fetch($result);

$code = explode('--', $_GET['code']);
$result2 = $sql->sql_query("SELECT * FROM postcode WHERE code = '".$code[0]."' LIMIT 1");
$row2 = $sql->sql_fetch($result2);

if(isset($row['id'])){
?>
<p class="abc1" style="font-family:'Arial';">Services in <?php echo     $row2['name']; ?>, <?php echo $row['city']; ?></p>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<?php
$result3 = $sql->sql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE city_id = '".$row['id']."' AND postcode = '".$row2['id']."'");
while($row3 = $sql->sql_fetch($result3)){

    $result4 = $sql->sql_query("SELECT * FROM cats WHERE id =     '".$row3['cat_id']."' LIMIT 1");
$row4 = $sql->sql_fetch($result4);

$one = str_replace(' ', '-', $row['city']);
$two = str_replace(' ', '-', $row2['name']);
$three = str_replace(' ', '-', $row4['name']);
$url = strtolower($one).'/'.$row2['code'].'--'.strtolower($two).'/'.strtolower($three).'/';
echo '<li class="list-link"><a href="http://www.450s.co/'.$url.'">'.$row4['name'].' in '.$row2['name'].', '.$row['city'].'</A></li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I assume that there is some php that will redirect after a form submission? The form submits the selected values ok so it is unclear from your question where the problem lies

Comment: please post the php code

Comment: the html is useless without the php that processes the form on the server.

Comment: It looks like your form is posting '$_GET['city']` with a number... maybe the ID? but then you search your MySQL for the city name. You probably need to change your SQL.

Comment: But i haven't changed any of the sql. I have only changed the index which is why i'm confused with what i've done. It was working perfectly until i re-did the html for the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Your form action says:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.450s.co/index.php">
```

but your PHP is looking for `$_GET['city']`

You probably need to change the form method like this:

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.450s.co/index.php">
```

Or else you need to do a search and replace on `$_GET` and replace it with `$_POST` in the PHP page.

Comment: It changed the url to this but still takes me to the homepage 'http://www.450s.co/index.php?city=5&code=1&cat=1&submit=GET+MY+DISCOUNT'

Comment: Which page contains the php code? is it index.php? If not you need to change your form action to be the page has the php code.  I looked at your page and it looks like it goes to page.php rather than index.php.  If that's where the php code resides, then your form tag needs to look like this: `<form method="get" action="http://www.450s.co/page.php">`